# Generic value class

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

Is it possible to define value class in scala for some `Numeric[T]`? I tried something like this:

```
case class Inches[T <: Numeric[T]](value: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]) extends AnyVal
```

However I get compilation error that `value classes can have only one parameter`.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the `Numeric` parameter from class to the methods which require it:

```
case class Inches[T](value: T) extends AnyVal {
  def foo()(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = ...
}
```

(`T <: Numeric[T]` is wrong.)